# Unable to locate credentials - Gitlab Pipeline for S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm deploying the front-end of my website to amazon s3 via Gitlab pipelines. My previous deployments have worked successfully but the most recent deployments do not. Here's the error:

```
Completed 12.3 MiB/20.2 MiB (0 Bytes/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
upload failed: dist/vendor.bundle.js.map to s3://<my-s3-bucket-name>/vendor.bundle.js.map Unable to locate credentials
```

Under my secret variables I have defined four. They are S3 credential variables `(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)` for two different buckets. One pair is for the **testing** branch and the other is for the **production** branch.

Not - the production environment variables are **protected** and the other variables are not.
Here's the deploy script that I run:

```
#/bin/bash
#upload files
aws s3 cp ./dist s3://my-url-$1 --recursive --acl public-read
```

So why am I getting this credential location error? Surely it should just pick up the environment variables automatically (the unprotected ones) and deploy them. Do I need to define the variables in the job and refer to them?

Comment: How are you supplying the AWS credentials to AWS CLI (`aws s3 ...`)?

Comment: @helloV I know I asked this question way back in April but this seems to be an ongoing thing. The AWS credentials should automatically get fed into the pipeline run Aws Cli in Gitlab in the same way they are automatically picked up when running via the terminal

Comment: This is hard to say without more specific details. How are you setting up the credentials? Do you have a runner executing the S3 command? 

One alternative to pulling credentials from environment variables is using an AWS profile. You could set up a profile on your runner and then update your command to use that profile (you wouldn't even need to change the command if it's the default profile). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

Comment: @colefner I'm setting up the credentials by setting the environment variables in Gitlab which should automatically get picked up when the job for deployment is kicked off. I don't have a runner executing the command as I believe they have to be manually set up. It seems that I'll probably have to go with that it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem was a collision to do with naming the variables. For both branches the variables were called `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. However the problem wasn't just to rename them as the pipeline still didn't pick them up.

I printed the password to the logs to determine which password was being picked up by which branch but found that neither was being taken up. The solution was to have a unique name for each password for each branch (e.g. `PRODUCTION_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `TESTING_ACCESS_KEY_ID`) and in the build script refer to them:

```
deploy_app_production:
  environment: 
    name: production
    url: <url>
  before_script:
    - echo "Installing ruby & dpl"
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby-full
    - gem install dpl
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - nv1
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to production"
    - sh deploy.sh production $PRODUCTION_ACCESS_KEY_ID $PRODUCTION_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  only:
    - master
```

And in the `deploy.sh` I referred to the passed in variables (though I did end up switching to [dpl](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl#s3)):

```
dpl --provider=s3 --access-key-id=$2 --secret-access-key=$3 --bucket=<my-bucket-name>-$1 --region=eu-west-1 --acl=public_read --local-dir=./dist --skip_cleanup=true
```

Answer (score 37):

(I encountered this issue many times - Adding another answer for people that have the same error - from other reasons).

**A quick checklist.**

Go to Setting -> CI/CD -> Variables and check:

1. If both `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` & `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables exist.
2. If both names are spelled right.
3. If their state is defined as `protected` - they can only be ran against `protected` branches (like `master`).

If error still occurs:

1. Make sure the access keys still exist and active on your account.
2. Delete current environment variables and replace them with new generated access keys and make sure `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` doesn't contain any special characters (can lead to strange errors).

Comment: No. 3 was the the catch for me...my branch was not protected while the env variable was set to protected

Comment: Step 3 helped me. Thanks

Comment: For Step 3: if you are running on a tag make sure the tag is marked as protected as well

Comment: Checking stepwise is helpful. Step 3 Worked. :)

Comment: #3 was a catch got me. Thanks.. you saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still struggling after reading the other answers, make sure your branch is protected if you are trying to read protected variables. Gitlab doesn't expose those variables to non-protected branches due to which you might see the error.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-project

To protect your branch go to Settings -> Repository -> Protected Branches and mark your required branch as protected. (This step might change in future)

Comment: yes and this is only correct answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the Docker image you use in your GitLab pipelines script locally, in interactive mode?

That way, you could verify that the environment variables not being picked up are indeed the problem. (I.e. if you set the same environment variables locally, and it works, then yes, that's the problem.)

I'm suspecting that maybe the credentials are picked up just fine, and maybe they just don't have all the required permissions to perform the requested operation. I know the error message says otherwise, but S3 error messages tend to be quite misleading when it comes to permission problems.

Comment: I'll investigate this and report back.